# Characterization of extreme points of the ball of $B(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis

The following is an exercise in Chapter 5, Section 7 of Conway's Functional Analysis text:

> If $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space, show that $T$ is an extreme point of $\text{ball }\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ if and only if either $T$ or $T^*$ is an isometry.

The ($\Leftarrow$) implication is due to both the fact that $\ell^2$ balls are strictly convex and the nature of the adjoint - other stackexchange posts talk about this. I have not been able to find an answer to ($\Rightarrow$) that a beginning student in functional analysis could also find.

Here is what I have so far:

1. If $\ker T$ and $\ker T^*$ both happen to be non-trivial - say $0\neq x\in\ker T$ and $0\neq y\in \ker T^*$ are of norm one - then we can perturb $T$ by a rank-one operator $S$ sending $x$ to $y$. Then if we decompose an arbitrary $z=\lambda x+\sqrt{1-\lambda^2}z_0$ for $z_0$ a norm-one element orthogonal to $x$ and $0\le \lambda\le 1$, we get 
   \begin{align*}\langle(T\pm S)z,(T\pm S)z\rangle&=\langle S\lambda x,S\lambda x\rangle+\langle T\sqrt{1-\lambda^2}z_0,T\sqrt{1-\lambda^2}z_0\rangle\pm2\langle x,T^*Sx\rangle\\
   &\le\lambda^2+1-\lambda^2\pm2\langle x,T^*y\rangle=1.\end{align*} Hence $T=\frac{1}{2}(T+S)+\frac{1}{2}(T-S)$, so $T$ is not an extreme point. This argument is restricted to $\mathbb{R}$-Hilbert spaces, and even this does not seem to generalize very nicely to other such spaces: for instance, in $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ if we define $T:=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$, then $\tilde{T}:=\frac{T}{\lVert T\rVert}$ is not an isometry and neither is its adjoint, $\tilde{T}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\tilde{T}^*\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ are both of norm less than one, but any perturbation of the operator by an operator of the form $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ \xi & 0\end{bmatrix}$ for $\xi\ge 0$ raises the operator norm of the matrix.
2. Murphy mentions this fact on page 137 and references Takesaki, Theorem I.10.2, for the proof. The theorem in Takesaki is done for a general C*-algebra and the proof utilizes the theory of operator algebras. The proof is a bit lengthy and (in my opinion) too clever for a student of Conway. Kadison-Ringrose also has a similar statement to that of Takesaki near the beginning of their second volume (Theorem 7.3.1), and this proof uses partial isometries and the Gelfand transform.

I am not contesting the more general proofs given above in (2) but am merely asking whether there is a simpler way to answer this problem in the specific case of our C*-algebra being $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ - perhaps one accessible to a reader of Conway.

Comment: @Song thank you, was about to reply with that

Comment: I see, I have stayed too long in differential geometry, where the word has a different meaning.

Comment: Further ideas: if we pass to the self-adjoint case, we might be able to get back by taking real and imaginary parts of an arbitrary operator. In the self-adjoint case, we get $\lVert T\rVert=\sup_{\lVert h\rVert=1}\{|\langle Th,h\rangle|\}$ by PII.2.13. Using this to do a calculation like the above with a sufficiently suppressed perturbation seems promising at the moment.